# How can I normalize mRNA samples for sequencing?

Tags: mrna, rna-sequencing

Is there an easy, inexpensive, not too labor intensive way to normalise mRNA samples so that even though one loses information of gene expression levels, each of the transcripts in the transcriptome is equally represented in the sample for sequencing? This is to say, one has a uniform distribution of transcripts, so that the lowly-expressed transcripts still have a good chance of being sequenced.

I have seen a few papers mentioning protocols for mRNA normalization, but I can't tell if any of them are practical in real life wet lab situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the link to a commercial product by Evrogen here:
http://www.evrogen.com/technologies/normalization.shtml

They claim their method is compatible with nextgen sequencing platforms:

> cDNA normalization using duplex-specific nuclease (DSN) is a highly
>   efficient approach that can be applied for normalization of
>   full-length-enriched cDNA (Zhulidov et al., 2004; Zhulidov et al.,
>   2005). The resulting cDNA contains equalized abundance of different
>   transcripts and can be used for construction of cDNA libraries and for
>   direct sequencing, including high-throughput sequencing on the next
>   generation sequencing platforms (Roche/454, ABI/SOLiD or
>   Illumina/Solexa).

And the most up-to-date reference seems to be this Curr Protoc Mol Biol. paper by Bogdanova et al.:
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20373503